# Incoporating PCPs in Wordpress

Tags: civicontribute, api, pcp

I'm trying to write some plugins to incorporate PCPs (mainly lists of them) into my Wordpress sites. I did not see in the API explorer any coverage of PCPs. (I could be blind, please feel free to correct me.)

I'd like to build a search feature, so that a visitor could search by multiple variables, like pcp owner name, or contribution campaign, etc. I'm also thinking of listing top fundraisers for a campaign.

I think I could write something using mysql queries but was wondering if there is a better way to go about it.

Answer (score 7):

PCPs don't have an API currently - but I just wrote one in about 15 minutes.  I didn't write unit tests, so I can't submit it upstream - maybe this is something you can help with to make CiviCRM better?

Paste the contents of this file into "Pcp.php" in your `civicrm/api/v3` folder: http://pastebin.com/cvzqfq69

There's some odd line of hyphens at the bottom, leave that off!
Next, in `civicrm/api/v3/util.php`, you should see a part that looks like:

```
  // FIXME: DAO names should follow CamelCase convention
  if ($name == 'Im' || $name == 'Acl') {
    $name = strtoupper($name);
  }
```

Change that "if" statement to:

```
  if ($name == 'Im' || $name == 'Acl' || $name == 'Pcp') {
```

That should get you a working PCP API!

Comment: Why not make a Pull Request for it.

Comment: APIs aren't accepted without a unit test - and I literally made this API in response to this question!  I can justify spending 15 minutes, but not several hours for writing tests.

Comment: its all about giving back to the community :)

Comment: Agreed - but I spend several hours a week giving back to the community!  In fact, I wrote both the StatusPreference and Soft Credit APIs as a volunteer.  I have a running list of "community improvements", and unfortunately this isn't very near the top :)