# API to load Personal Campaign Pages

Tags: drupal, contacts, civicampaign, personal-campaign-pages

I've explored the APIs for CiviCRM 4.7.

I can't seem to find an entity for PCP or Personal Campaigns. Tried using the campaigns API but personal campaigns don't come up with it.

Does anyone know of the PCP API and have some sample code?

I've tried

```
$result = civicrm_api3('Campaign', 'get', array(
            'sequential' => 1,
           // "created_id" => $contactId,
        ));
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an "unofficial" api for pcp from Jon:
https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/3037/246

It would be super useful if you could contribute the needed tests and add it to the core. You know you want to ;)

Answer (score 0):

Campaign is a different entity than PCP (it's part of civicampaign) so not the right one indeed

Answer (score 0):

This feature has been added to version 4.6

https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/4.6/contributions/personal-campaign-pages/

https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/9049