# Where can I get the code that creates the progress bar for Personal Campaign Pages?

Tags: personal-campaign-pages

When creating a Contribution Page, you can enable a widget and copy the code to create a progress bar wherever you want. I'd like to do that with some personal campaign pages, so that they are all on the same front-facing webpage to show who is winning a fundraising competition. I'm not finding an obvious way to do that, but I expect it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure there's an 'easy' way to do it (similar to the widget code for an entire Contribution page). In the past I've done something like it by writing a custom plugin (for Wordpress) that used mysql queries to pull data from active PCPs. I don’t believe there’s a fully operational API for PCPs yet - that would probably let you avoid writing queries yourself - there is however an unofficial API that you might find useful.

[Incoporating PCPs in Wordpress](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3030/incoporating-pcps-in-wordpress/3037#3037)

Comment: Thanks for the info. We use Joomla, and I think this would be more work than I could justify for this one use. I was hoping for code somewhere like the Contrib widget, but if that's not the case, I'll live.